# How to extend MYSQL's database naming limit

Tags: mysql, database

I've an application that requires very large database names. I have read on SO that if you require more than the 128 characters limit allowed for database names then there's something wrong with you software design. Be assured we've thought of this, and still require larger database names.

I thought MYSQL was open source, meaning anybody can grab a copy and code it, but looking at their website I wouldn't know where to start, if this is even so.

**a)** Can the MYSQL database naming limit be extended to 1024+ characters and

**b)** How would we do that?

**c)** If it can't be recoded (eg if it's not open source or the code is not available) then are there any other free Open Source, Robust and Largely Supported, database engines that allow names as long as we want to make them?

**d)** We would also like to be able to name tables longer than 128 characters.

Comment: Why would you need 128-char database name? I often do well with no more than 10. Even 6 is more than enough. I rarely have more than a dozen databases per instance.

Comment: "Be assured we've thought of this". Yeah, well, *think harder*. You really, really do not want to roll out a custom-compiled MySQL in production. MySQL is relatively luxurious in allowing 128 characters, as Postgres is only 63.

Comment: This sounds like a huge XY Problem. What are you doing that necessitates such long names? Why couldn't you use a shorter representation? 128 characters allows for 1.3x10^181 possible alphabetic names. **Surely that is enough**. It honestly sounds like you need a way of compressing the information down into a more compact format, or using different databases instead of innumerable tables.

Comment: It might help us help you if you wrote a bit more about **why** you need the object names in your data design to be large enough to bear information. Do you want them to be random and hard to guess? To carry user names? Or what? Please [edit] your question.

Comment: Ok. I'll have another look at our design. It's just that, we want to be able to update database tables by doing a php foreach loop and this would be easier if we had longer more definitive database names.

Comment: @O . Jones Yes, we do want them to be differcult to guess certainly. Also, the more definitive and admin-friendly the names, the easier it is to do a foreach. I'm just thinking now though that, there might be a way to update user's databases by first (upon login) checking for a database/table/record update, and if so, apply it then, instead of using a foreach loop.